# Download via ASP.NET can impact IIS performance?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, file-upload, file-io

I doing a upload system for my blog engine and thinking if is a good idea to store my files at database/app_data. Or I should store at a normal folder with write permission.

My concern is about downloading large files through ASP.NET. ASP.NET will hold a thread until client ends the download?

Answer (score 0):

when there is a limitation of requests per second of IIS, so if download a large file, IIS will spent more time to maintence the connection between client and server.

Obvoiusly download a large file will impact IIS performance

Comment: But has any difference if the file comes direct from disk, a static file, or from asp.net (download.axd?file=myfile.zip)?